# Manipulating multiple objects by their name in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, loops, object

How is it possible to manipulate multiple objects in a loop. For example you have 30 buttons and want to change their background color. They are called button1, button2 and so on.

```
for (int i=1; i<31; i++)
{
    button+i.BACKGROUND.COLOR = AWESOME.BACKGROUND.COLOR;
}
```

So what is the right Syntax for "button+i." or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Put them in a `Collection` and then work with that `Collection`.

Comment: Why not create an array or list of buttons for this?

Comment: WPF? WinForms? WebForms? MVC? ...?

Comment: C# syntax to use indices is by using `[]`, so if you loop over a `Button[]`, access them with `button[i].BACKGROUND.COLOR = ...`

Comment: What do you mean "They are called button1, button2 and so on."? Where are the buttons stored and where are the names stored?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put all the buttons in a list then use foreach?

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
//at some point, in a constructor or Loaded event add all the buttons that have been created to the list
foreach(var button in buttons)
{
}
```

You could theoretically get the buttons via reflection and add them to a list, at some point when you know the buttons will exist:

```
var t = this.GetType();

var fields = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                     BindingFlags.Instance);
//assuming you are doing this in a xaml.cs, if not you may need to change
// the above to GetProperties or use Public flag, depending on how your buttons
// are defined.
foreach (var f in fields)
{
    if (f.FieldType == typeof (Button))
        _buttons.Add(f.GetValue(this));

}
```